# AsyncStorage saving multiple items

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

I want to store multiple phone numbers with name. I am using AsyncStorage.

```
    storeData = async (value) => {
        try {
            var number = [['name', this.state.name], ['number', this.state.number]];
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@following', JSON.stringify(number));
        } catch (e) {

        }
    };
```

Everything works fine, it is saving the data. But how about if i want to add one more number to my existing data? When i try it now, it overwrites the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* In Order to update followers List need to perform these steps

1. Get the followers array from AsyncStorage.
2. Push the new followers to the array.
3. Update the followers array in AsyncStorage.

*/
```

```js
async addNewFollower(name, number) {
  let existingFollowers = await this.getExistingFollowers();
  const updatedFollowers= [...existingFollowers, [name, number]]
  console.log("Updated followers", updatedFollowers);
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(
    "@following", 
    JSON.stringify(updatedFollowers)
  );
}

async getExistingFollowers() {
  let followers = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@following");
  console.log("followers", followers);
  return followers ? JSON.parse(followers) : [];
}
```